# Making a t-distribution with sample size less than 30

Tags: t-distribution

Our teacher said that we can use the graph of a standard normal distribution whenever the sample size is greater than or equal to 30 because of CLT. How can we make a graph of a $t$-distribution if the sample size is less than 30? What I mean is that if the standard normal distribution is like $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{x^{2}}},$$ what should a $t$-distribution be?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Definition)?

Comment: What do you mean by "use the graph"? How would you use the graph.

Comment: You appear to be asking what a formula for the Student t density function (pdf) might be: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=student%20t%20pdf.